# I am trying to convert any dict to a list through a function, but it's not working and can't find out why

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, type-conversion

```
dict1 = {}
list1 = []

   def convert_to_list(entry):
    """ ... """
    for k, v in dict1:
        entry = (k, dict1[v])
        new_list = list1.append(entry)
    return new_list


convert_to_list({'a': 1})
```

Even when I define new_list globally it still doesn't work.
Can you please take a look and help me fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How is it supposed to work and what does it do currently? Hint: to iterate over key/value pairs in a dict, use `dict.items()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in the method that you have written:

1. you are passing entry as parameter to the method but you are trying to access elements in dict1 which is currently empty.
2. in for loop, you should use `entry.items()` instead of just dict1
3. `append` method does return a new list, it just adds elements to existing list.
   so you should use `new_list.append()`

```
In [10]: def convert_to_list(entry): 
    ...:     new_list=[] 
    ...:     for k,v in entry.items(): 
    ...:         print(k,v) 
    ...:         entry1 = (k,v) 
    ...:         new_list.append(entry1) 
    ...:     return new_list 
    ...:                                                                        

In [11]:                                                                        

In [11]: convert_to_list({'a':1})                                               
a 1
Out[11]: [('a', 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I hope in a very near future I can help others too.

Comment: if the answer helped you, please upvote or accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a dict to a list of tuples like this:

```py
def convert_to_list(entry):
    """ ... """
    return list(entry.items())


entry_list = convert_to_list({'a': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue what you are doing:

```
def dicttolist(dictx):
    return list(dictx.items())
```

This will turn any doct to what it seems that you are trying to do

```
dicttolist({'a':1})
>>> [('a',1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looping through `dict1`, not the argument. Also, you can't do

```py
for k, v in entry:
```

Because then it's trying to unpack a tuple. You have to do

```py
for k in entry:
```

And access elements of `entry` using `.get()`. This is working code for that function:

```py
def convert_to_list(entry):
    """ ... """
    new_list = [] # Create a new list
    for k in entry: # Loop through entry's keys
        new_list.append((k, entry.get(k))) # append the key and value (the value has been found using .get())
    return new_list # return the list
```